# Display waiting animation during AJAX request

Tags: javascript, ajax, extjs

I would like to dispay a simple waiting animation while getting data from the server using an AJAX request.
This is the code of the request :

```
new Ajax.Request(prefix + 'modelling/', {
                method: 'get',
                asynchronous: false,
                requestHeaders: {
                    "Accept":"application/json"
                },
                parameters: {
                    id: 'getcaplist',

                },
                encoding: 'UTF-8',
                onSuccess: function(response){
                    console.log('response : ', response);


                    var resJSON = response.responseText.evalJSON();
                    console.log('resJSON: ', resJSON);

                    for(var I = 0; I < resJSON.length; ++i){
                      //do something with obj[i]
                        for(var ind in resJSON[i]) {
                        console.log(ind);
                            for(var vals in resJSON[i][ind]){
                            console.log(vals, resJSON[i][ind][vals]);
                            capabilities.push(resJSON[i][ind][vals]);

                            }
                        }
                    }
                    console.log('capabilities', capabilities);

                }.bind(this),

                onException: function(){
                    Ext.Msg.alert(ORYX.I18N.Oryx.title, 'Exception while getting capabilities list').setIcon(Ext.Msg.WARNING).getDialog().setWidth(260).center().syncSize();

                }.bind(this),
                onFailure: (function(transport) {
                    Ext.Msg.alert(ORYX.I18N.Oryx.title, ORYX.I18N.Hbpmn.getFailure).setIcon(Ext.Msg.WARNING).getDialog().setWidth(260).center().syncSize();

                }).bind(this),
                on401: (function(transport) {
                    Ext.Msg.alert(ORYX.I18N.Oryx.title, ORYX.I18N.Hbpmn.getFailure).setIcon(Ext.Msg.WARNING).getDialog().setWidth(260).center().syncSize();
                                        }).bind(this),
                on403: (function(transport) {
                    Ext.Msg.alert(ORYX.I18N.Oryx.title, ORYX.I18N.Hbpmn.getFailure).setIcon(Ext.Msg.WARNING).getDialog().setWidth(260).center().syncSize();

                }).bind(this)
            });
```

The waiting animation should be hided, when passing to the onSucess function.

Comment: prior to your ajax request call a wheel or progress library.show(); Then in your onSuccess block do .hide(). Simple as that

Comment: any example please ? I didn't understand what you mean

Comment: `asynchronous: false,` will make it impossible for anything to animate during the ajax request.

Comment: @KevinB - HAHAH! I just noticed that. Please change to true Khouloud. It defeats the whole purpose of "A"jax

Comment: can you please add **Signavio** tag ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change `asynchronous: false`

Answer (score -2):

You have to use the onLoading method like this:

```
new Ajax.Request(prefix + 'modelling/', {
                method: 'get',
                asynchronous: false,
                requestHeaders: {
                    "Accept":"application/json"
                },
                parameters: {
                    id: 'getcaplist',

                },
                encoding: 'UTF-8',
                onLoading: function(){
                    // DO SOMETHING HERE
                },
                onSuccess: function(response){
                    console.log('response : ', response);


                    var resJSON = response.responseText.evalJSON();
                    console.log('resJSON: ',resJSON);

                    for(var i = 0; i < resJSON.length; ++i){
                      //do something with obj[i]
                        for(var ind in resJSON[i]) {
                        console.log(ind);
                            for(var vals in resJSON[i][ind]){
                            console.log(vals, resJSON[i][ind][vals]);
                            capabilities.push(resJSON[i][ind][vals]);

                            }
                        }
                    }
                    console.log('capabilities', capabilities);

                }.bind(this),

                onException: function(){
                    Ext.Msg.alert(ORYX.I18N.Oryx.title, 'Exception while getting capabilities list').setIcon(Ext.Msg.WARNING).getDialog().setWidth(260).center().syncSize();

                }.bind(this),
                onFailure: (function(transport) {
                    Ext.Msg.alert(ORYX.I18N.Oryx.title, ORYX.I18N.Hbpmn.getFailure).setIcon(Ext.Msg.WARNING).getDialog().setWidth(260).center().syncSize();

                }).bind(this),
                on401: (function(transport) {
                    Ext.Msg.alert(ORYX.I18N.Oryx.title, ORYX.I18N.Hbpmn.getFailure).setIcon(Ext.Msg.WARNING).getDialog().setWidth(260).center().syncSize();
                                        }).bind(this),
                on403: (function(transport) {
                    Ext.Msg.alert(ORYX.I18N.Oryx.title, ORYX.I18N.Hbpmn.getFailure).setIcon(Ext.Msg.WARNING).getDialog().setWidth(260).center().syncSize();

                }).bind(this)
            });
```

have a look at the [documentation](http://api.prototypejs.org/ajax/Ajax/Request/). onLoading maps to the Initialize stage in the XHR's life cycle. Therefore, here would be a proper place to initialize a loading gif or similar.

Comment: i'm afraid there's nothing you can do in any of the ajax events that will result in anything rendering in the browser before the **synchronous** ajax request is sent.

Comment: Thanks! That was a to fast copy paste from the [prototypejs](http://prototypejs.org/) site. It is corrected.

Comment: The only possible way would be to wrap the entire ajax request in a setTimeout, but that will likely break other code that relies on the request being sent synchronously.

Comment: onLoading maps to the Initialize stage in the XHR's life cycle. Therefore, it should be equivalent to beforeSend in jQuery, and to my knowledge that is the best place to show an loading gif no?

Comment: Yes, but the problem is the callstack will not clear until long after the ajax request has completed. Until the callstack clears, the browser will be unable to render anything. If this were an **Asynchronous** request, your answer would be correct.